# How to schedule tests and store the tests reports?

Tags: java, integration-testing, jenkins

I have a few integration tests (java classes), which test a server application. (the tests just send requests, receive responses and verify them). Now I  would like to run the tests periodically (e.g. nightly), store the test reports somehow in a database, and run queries like "which tests failed against build #xxx".

Should I use Jenkins? Is there any other open source java software for this task? Is there any web service, which can run my integration tests against my server and store the reports in a database?

Answer (score 2):

Neither Jenkins nor CruiseControl store your test results in a database. But Jenkins does store the test results of your builds, and displays some graphs where you can see how the test results evolve over time. Also Jenkins can tell since how many builds a test has been broken and similar information.

You can take a look on the Jenkins of the Jenkins project, [here](http://ci.jenkins-ci.org/view/All%20Unstable/job/plugins_collabnet/) is a project where you can see some tests failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cruisecontrol, similiar to jenkins.
But if you are running just a script, you can have it executed with periodically with windows schedular or cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Jenkins** for test scheduling and report creation , Maven (surefire) and **TestNG** for definition and running the tests - works well.